# Grinding noise when releasing the accelerator pedal

Tags: noise, mitsubishi, grinding

I have a really annoying grinding noise coming from the front of my car, this only happens whenever I release the accelerator after cruising. The grinding will only stop if I push the accelerator or hitting the brake.

I cant replicate this grinding noise if the car is stationary, only when cruising.

What you guys think? my usual mechanic cant find anything wrong and instead want to try and replace my cv joint, but there is no grinding noise when I make a turn.

The car have just got all rear and front brake pads replaced around 2 weeks ago before this grinding start, not sure if related..

Comment: Some information about the car and type of transmission might be useful

Comment: its a 2007 mitsubishi 380 with automatic transmission.

Comment: This is the closest example of how it sounds like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5WsgcQ6BaY, from 20 sec-26 second mark. Seems like the guy who posted this video has similar problems.